# The usage of "in + past tense of a verb"

Tags: word-usage

> Then the wolf was very angry indeed, and declared he would eat up the
>   little pig, and that he would get down the chimney after him. When the
>   little pig saw what he was about, he hung on the pot full of water,
>   and made up a blazing fire, and, just as the wolf was coming down,
>   took off the cover, and **in fell** the wolf; so the little pig put on the
>   cover again in an instant, boiled him up, and ate him for supper, and
>   lived happy ever afterwards.

This is from "The story of The Three Little Pigs" in English fairy tales.

I think "in fell the wolf" means "the wolf fell in the pot" but I don't know the usage of "in + a past tense of a verb" like "in fell". The usage like this is commonly used?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, this is just a different way to say "the wolf fell in [the pot]".

It is not a special structure with 'in' and verb past tenses, just a different arrangement of "fall in". It is informal/colloquial English.

You can do the same with other verbs indicating prepositions like 'go up' or 'run out':

"He let go of the balloon, and up it went."

"I open the front door, and out runs the cat."

Comment: This structure is also common in children's books or rhymes, for example ['Then woosh went the wind, and out went the lights...'](http://thingsthatgoboo.com/scarypoems/dpfivelittlepumpkins.htm). It lends itself to a certain rhythm when you read the book.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of an old-fashioned way of saying "the wolf fell in the pot".  It's less of a "in + past tense of a verb" and more of mixing around where the prepositional phrase is.

Take this:

> The wolf fell in the pot.

"In the pot" is the prepositional phrase.  If you move it around, you get:

> In the pot fell the wolf.

(This form is not common, but it still is grammatically correct.)  If you remove a few words (as English-speakers tend to do for convenience), it becomes:

> In fell the wolf.

And this is the sentence in that story!

Comment: It's not really old-fashioned, it's just a literary device. http://literary-devices.com/content/hyperbaton

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. It is a common usage in story telling, particularly for children. It puts the emphasis on the direction of motion.

> "The itsy bitsy spider climbed up the water spout, **down came** the rain and washed the spider out."

But it could also be used in conversation, for a comedic effect.

> "I told Joe not to run next to the pool. It's slippery! Next thing you know, in falls Joe, and his mother goes into panic mode."