# What's the meaning " the trade has a golden foundation "?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

> As he was going through the last village, there stood a
>   scissors-grinder with his barrow; as his wheel whirred he sang --
>
> "I sharpen scissors and quickly grind, My coat blows out in the wind
>   behind." Hans stood still and looked at him; at last he spoke to him
>   and said, "All's well with you, as you are so merry with your
>   grinding." - "Yes," answered the scissors-grinder, "**the trade has a**
>   **golden foundation**. A real grinder is a man who as often as he puts his
>   hand into his pocket finds gold in it. But where did you buy that fine
>   goose?"

This is a short story "Hans in Luck" from Grimms' Fairy Tales. Could you teacn me the meaning  " the trade has a golden foundation "?

Comment: The "trade" is scissor-grinding", and "golden foundation" means a perfect basis for building one's occupation successfully. Could you be more specific which word(s) are troubling you?

Comment: It's not a native Anglophone thing to say. It's just [a translation of a Danish proverb.](http://www.special-dictionary.com/proverbs/source/d/danish_proverb/73248.htm) For that reason, I think this question is essentially Off Topic in the context of learning *English.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's understandable in English whether you are familiar with the Danish proverb or not though, and the question gives enough context for someone to write an answer. It appears that there is a free e-book version of Grimm's fairy tales that a lot of learners are reading, so I'm reluctant to close these questions just because the language isn't usual. http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/91147/9161

Comment: @ColleenV: If it's "understandable", it's not worth posing as a question here. The translated version has no particular history or currency in an *English* context - the fact is it's trivial to interpret the (unfamiliar to most native speakers) metaphoric usage. Would a question asking the meaning of *golden opportunity* be On Topic? I don't think so.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Understandable for a fluent English speaker shouldn't make a question off-topic. I don't think it is as trivial as it looks for someone learning English - trade, golden, and foundation all have multiple definitions that might be hard to choose from. If I were to close this question, it would be because the asker doesn't explain why a dictionary didn't help and not because it's patently trivial. I suppose that's tomayto/tomahto though.

Comment: @ColleenV: But it's only *marginally* comprehensible to native Anglophones anyway. Obviously we all know that ***gold*** itself is valuable (whatever language we speak), and all native speakers know that we can use metaphoric ***golden** [opportunity]* to mean *valuable*. But apart from *golden **goose*** (so named because it lays *golden **eggs***, also derived from Northern European folklore), I'm not aware of any idiomatic usages where it means *lucrative, wealth-producing*. This particular metaphoric usage is not characteristic of English, so it shouldn't be learnt/taught/endorsed here.

Comment: ...in short, a *Danish* person would find this usage easier to understand than a native Anglophone, and since the very next sentence in OP's cited context *fully explains* the significance anyway, I'm sticking to my guns. (Or at least, to my *tomahtoes!* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The trade has a golden foundation."

This basically means The trade (job) of the scissor-grinder (that of sharpening scissors) has a golden foundation (is very lucrative.)

The implication is that anyone who takes up the trade of sharpening scissors is going to make a lot of money.  This is supported by the next sentence:

> "A real grinder is a man who as often as he puts his hand into his pocket finds gold in it."

Meaning every time he puts his hand into his pocket, he has gold to retrieve.

In simpler terms, he never runs out of money.